# Set min and max value for multivalue, and at same time XPM also able to add/remove value

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

I have a component link multivalued field in a schema for which I have set minoccurs as 1 and maxoccurs as 3.
But when I set the min and max occurrences of field, I am not able to add/remove the field from XPM.
If I remove the min and max occurrences and leave it as default then I am able to add/remove the field through XPM.
Below is the code of dwt template for same:

```
@@FieldStartMarker("highlight_list")@@
  <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields.highlight_list" -->
    @@FieldValueStartMarker(TemplateRepeatIndex)@@
    <div class="noTheming promoLable">
      @@RenderComponentPresentation(Field, GetTcmUriWebDavURI("/path/Title.tctcmp"))@@
    </div>
    @@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
  <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
@@FieldEndMarker()@@
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

Setting MaxOccurs to anything but 1 or unbounded in the schema is a customization which is not fully supported by all parts of the Tridion GUI. The problem is that Tridion now no longer recognizes the field as a multi value field (which requires MaxOccurs=unbounded) and adjusts the behaviour of the GUI accordingly.

The easiest solution is to set MaxOccurs to unbounded (which is what the Tridion GUI expects) and make checks for the number of values in the field in code (if you want to enforce a maximum of three; a simple event system comes to mind here).